# Are there websites where I can learn Python algorithms "in the browser"

Tags: python, resources

I am learning algorithms in Python right now. Are there websites where I can learn these algorithms "in the browser" with byte-size lessons, like Codecademy and Freecodecamp have, free or paid?

Comment: I think hackerRank can also be a good option, you'll practice both problem solving and coding simultaneously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking at codility.com. a great site for learning algorithms in python

Answer (score 1):

so I really liked hackerrank.com for learning algorithms. It has a special section for that and even more.

if you have 10€/10$ left, there are courses on Udemy on sale sometime, maybe you can find one for algorithms too